# Play Global object (GlobalSettings) not being executed

Tags: playframework-2.0

I ran my application successfully on a server, with a custom config file specified on the command line using:

```
-Dconfig.file=app.conf
```

but when I tried to copy the custom config file to my local machine and use it there, by passing `-Dconfig.file` to `run`, strange errors started to appear. I eventually traced this to my Global object's `onStart` method not being executed at all. Why is this happening?

Comment: Use `play -Dconfig.file=conf/app.conf` (note, that added 'conf/' prefix')

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the typesafe config library was silently failing to load this line in my custom config file

```
include "application"
```

but only from `sbt run` - it worked when running the application standalone on a server.

Therefore the `application.global=global.Global` line wasn't being read in that file, so Play couldn't find the `Global` object, and silently fell back to an empty `Global` object that does nothing.

Changing the `include` line to specify an absolute file path to `application.conf` fixed the problem.